# Is there a way to get a difference report on two Jet (.mdb) databases?

Tags: database, ms-access, diff

I have code that depends a relatively small MS Jet (created in Access) database. Our source control process is far from all that it could/should be (which is a problem that needs to be solved immediately) and we have ended up with two versions of the same database. The person who edited the "other" version is no longer around to give me hints about what he changed. What is the best way to find the differences of the actual data contained in two versions of a database?

Comment: Is this a data or application question? That is, do you mean you need to compare data tables stored in a Jet MDB, or do you mean that you need to compare forms/reports/etc. between the two? If the latter, the suggestion of SaveAsText by Remou is the best solution.

Comment: Do you have a unique key for each table?

Comment: Are you asking if every table has a primary key? If so, yes every table has a primary key. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you are asking. Sorry, databases are not a place where I have much experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output all the forms and modules to text files and use a text compare utility.

For example:

```
Sub ToText()
Dim frm, mdl

For Each frm In CurrentProject.AllForms
    Application.SaveAsText acForm, frm.Name, "c:\docs\" _ 
        & frm.Name & ".txt"
```

'SO formatting

```
Next

For Each mdl In CurrentProject.AllModules
    Application.SaveAsText acModule, mdl.Name, "c:\docs\" _
        & mdl.Name & ".txt"
```

'SO formatting

```
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the deal with those 'SO formatting' comments stuck in our excellent answer?

Comment: I put them in because SO formats VBA in an odd way. And thanks for the excellent :)

Comment: Remou - Why not indent the comments as well? Is it just because SO interprets the apostrophe as the start of a string and is coloured wrong?

Comment: It is not just apostrophes that are the problem, slashes are too, and you cannot fix slashes with an extra apostrophe. so I got bored with fixing both problems. Half the time these days I don't even bother with double apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this http://www.download.com/StarInix-Database-Compare/3000-10254_4-10614062.html

Comment: This will be useful only if the question is about DATA, not about an Access application. This is, of course, the point of confusion that is endemic on StackOverflow.com, where too may people don't distinguish between Access and Jet.

Answer (score 0):

Ther are tools that can do this like: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/DatabaseCompare.html

Or you can look at created / modified dates to see if that gives you a clue (change the database window to show details)

Or you can run the Tools / Analyze / Documenter and look at the object properties.

Comment: This is a GREAT option if you can afford it...fms tools are expensive but they target access and work very well.

Seth

Answer (score 0):

I've made an application that allows to compare and import/export database objects between two Microsoft Access files (mdb or accdb). It is called "AccdbMerge" and can be downloaded here:
https://ksdbmerge.tools/accdbmerge

Basically, it automates the method provided by Remou